# Expected size of a set A

Tags: expected-value

Let $I=\{1,2,\ldots, 1000\}$. Let $A$ be an empty set.
I take a random integer from $I$ with replacement and put in $A$. I do this process 1000 times.
What is the expected size of $A$?

This is my approach.

Let $X_i$ be binary random variable which takes 1 iff $i$-th integer is different from previous drawn integers.

Then probaility of $X_i=1$ is $\frac{1000-(X_1+\ldots+X_{i-1})}{1000}$. Then our target is to find $\sum_{i=1}^{1000} E(X_i)$.

Definitely $E(X_1)=1$, $E(X_2)=\frac{999}{1000}$ etc. I would like to know whether this approach is correct. I know this problem is very close to coupan collector problem.

I think another idea. Let $X_i$ be the number of different intger upto $i$-th round. Then $X_{i+1}$ becomes $1+X_i$ with probability $\frac{1000-X_i}{1000}$. I am trying some recursive relation.

Comment: What have you tried ? where are you stuck ? Do you take numbers from $I$ with replacement ? if not, then $|A|=1000$...

Comment: Your reputation suggests that you have been in this site long enough to know that giving just a problem statement as a question will end up in downvotes.

Comment: Sorry. Now I have added my idea.